# Are there tools to check whether changes to a C++ class will break a previous version of that class?

Tags: c++, abi

If you've been programming in C++ for a while, you probably ran a program that crashed "for no obvious reason" to find out that the ABI of the library was not compatible anymore and all you had to do was recompile the software against the new version of the library.

The reason the ABI breaks are multiple: change in virtual table, adding/removing constructors, destructor, or variable members...

What I'm wondering is this: is there a tool that can be used to compare two class definitions (old version and current version) and tell me whether they are ABI compatible or not.

This would be useful to determine the version of my project (i.e. if the ABI changed, I was to go from 1.2.7 to 1.3.0, if the ABI did not change, I just go to 1.2.8).

Many people who program in C++ have had this problem. A good example is Qt which clearly states that patches will not break binary compatibility (although once in a while they make a mistake, but generally, their code is quite solid).

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Version-Compatibility
http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/is_qt_binary_compatible

However, Qt has staff that can spend time in verifying (all manually?) that the public classes have not changed in a way that would break compatibility. I couldn't say as much of many much smaller C++ projects.

Comment: I assume you mean two definitions *including* the definitions of any other objects used by that class.

Comment: Yes. To know whether they are binary compatible.

Comment: Isn't this verbatim what compilers along with a proper build system, and use of makefiles, does?

Comment: Which compiler(s) are you interested in (this question is compiler-specific since the language makes no mention of ABI).

Comment: @ChrisCM It can be a problem with third party libraries.  You install the headers, but forget to upgrade the library, or vice versa.

Comment: @James: I would argue a proper build system/set of processes would couple those two things together, and is precisely my point.  The OP's belief that something like this should exist is a comment that there is a problem with his process, not a need for a new/special tool.

Comment: @MarkB I could imagine that in some cases there could be difference between compilers, but it seems to me that whatever the compiler the result should be the same. Hmmm... maybe memory wise class member alignment could play a role. Anyway, I use g++ and VC 2010 at this point.

Comment: @ChrisCM I will give you a link to maybe prove that I know what I'm talking about: http://windowspackager.org/documentation/build-system-wpkg -- my problem is that I package each project in binary form and each project has dependencies on other projects. I can recompile everything when a dependency changes. That's very easy to do and already working. However, the version MUST be bumped up when that happens. However, having to recompile all the projects that depend on a low level library every time a comment changes does not seem wise to me.

Comment: A broken link to a bad windows build system doesn't prove or disprove anything.  If you need to make comment changes, after changes to a low level library, perhaps you should consider modifying your process to include the comment changes prior to new builds.  Otherwise you have guaranteed that your documentation at some point, was incorrect and out of date, a bad practice, and further evidence that my comment about this being a "process" issue is valid.

Comment: @ChrisCM The link will certainly work later today, the IP changed recently and you are probably getting the old one... Note that when your documentation is over 1Mb it is always out of date. But I do stand my ground about the usefulness of detecting whether changes are binary compatible or not. I'm sorry you cannot see my problem the way it is. Thank you for taking the time to comment though.

Comment: I see your problem the way it is.  Many before you have seen the same problem.  They all came to the same conclusion: file modification is justification enough for a re-build.  If others before you had come to the alternative conclusion then surely the stackoverflow C++ community would have flooded you with dozens of links to build systems that support what you want in hopes of gaining reputation.

Comment: If you only change comment, or spacing, then binary should not change (only timestamps)...

Comment: @ChrisCM By that definition, there are no proper build systems.  None of the ones I know have anything to do with the installation of libraries.

Comment: @ChrisCM There was one system, Visual Age.  I don't know what its current status is, but it didn't use classical header files, but kept all of the sources, and their pre-compiled equivalents, in a data base, and it knew what changes required recompilation, and which ones didn't.  (A quick glance at the IBM products pages suggest that this product has been discontinued, in favor a an Eclipse based IDE.)

Comment: @James: I would agree, the perfect build system does not exist, only ones with fewer weaknesses than the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux there is an [abi-compliance-checker](http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/) tool. It can be used to verify backward binary compatibility of your C++ library. See sample reports of the tool for the Qt library: http://abi-laboratory.pro/tracker/timeline/qt/

You need to compile debug version of your library with addition `-g -Og` options and dump ABI of your library with the help of the [abi-dumper](https://github.com/lvc/abi-dumper) tool. And then compare two ABI dumps of different versions to generate ABI changes report.

[image]

Comment: Is there a difference between `-O0` and `-Og`? I am used to `-O0` for debug builds.

Answer (score 2):

Formally, if you've changed any token in the class definition,
they're not compatible.  Otherwise...  I don't know of any tool,
since most people wouldn't accept the risk if they've changed
anything.  And since most people will be using make or something
similar, anytime anything changes in the header (including
correcting a misspelling in a comment), they will automatically
recompile all of the sources which include the header, directly
or indirectly.

The only problem comes if you've been playing around with the
file timestamps.  And the answer to that is: don't do it.

Finally, for managing versions, I change the version (visible
outside my own build structures) anytime I change anything which
might change the interface.  And I mangle the version number
into the library namespace, so you can't link code with the
wrong version of the library.  But this is really only necessary
if you're delivering the library and headers to other people.
(And probably not even then—most programmers I know will
automatically do a clean build whenever they upgrade any of the
libraries they're using.)

Comment: If I recompile everything, there are no problems, indeed. Now assume that I put library A in a binary package. Will project B, which is itself in a binary package, need to be recompiled and a new package generated? Or will the old version of project B work with the new version of library A?

Comment: @AlexisWilke If you export a new version of the library, every project that uses it must be recompiled.  Transitively, because you'll be exported new versions of the other libraries which use it as well.

Comment: If all you do are fixes in the code and comment changes, then project B does not need to be recompiled (assuming library A is offered as a dynamic library, .so or .DLL, obviously.) If you are handling 1,000 packages, it would be terrible to have to recompile everything every time, I think.

Comment: @AlexisWilke If it's an external library, you don't update that often (and you regroup your updates), so recompiling everything is acceptable (and necessary).  (And if you've got 1000 DLLs, you're doing something wrong.)

Comment: James, do you have any idea how many packages there are in a system like Debian? Okay, all are not libraries, but that's still quite a large % and I'm pretty sure that's over 1,000.